# How to save output in different file after clip

Tags: arcpy, clip, workspace

I am new to GIS.

I have several rasters in one file location

I am using clip tool to loop over several rasters in arcgis. When I start I am choosing workspace, which is the folder where my input files are. However after clip I want to save output into different file. I could not figure it out how to do.

Can you please show me?

Here is my code.

---

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Setting working directory
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\Research\arcgis"

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

# Local variables:
Tr_pro = "D:\\Tr2009\\admin\\Trpro.shp"
Tr_lyr = "D:\\Tr2009\\admin\\Trlayer"
Tr_dist = "D:\\Tr2009\\admin\\Trdist.shp"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Tr_dist, Tr_lyr)

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Tr_lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", "\"Name\" = 'Adi'")

rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("F*")
for raster in rasterList:
    arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "25.665181 35.812875 44.826408 42.104629", "M"+str(raster[1:]), Tr_lyr, "255", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

---

If i use this code, it saves all output into the workspace that I defined in the beginning. However I want to save it to another location such as "D:\Tr2009\admin\output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an output path parameter (`outputPath = "D:\\Tr2009\\admin\\output\\"`) and use that for your output raster in your clip e.g.

```
arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "25.665181 35.812875 44.826408 42.104629", outputPath + "M"+str(raster[1:]), Tr_lyr, "255", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

Here is your code again with the above changes:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Setting working directory
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\Research\arcgis"

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

# Local variables:
Tr_pro = "D:\\Tr2009\\admin\\Trpro.shp"
Tr_lyr = "D:\\Tr2009\\admin\\Trlayer"
Tr_dist = "D:\\Tr2009\\admin\\Trdist.shp"

outputPath = "D:\\Tr2009\\admin\\output\\"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Tr_dist, Tr_lyr)

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Tr_lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", "\"Name\" = 'Adi'")

rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("F*")
for raster in rasterList:
    arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "25.665181 35.812875 44.826408 42.104629", outputPath + "M"+str(raster[1:]), Tr_lyr, "255", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it was a minor thing but could not figure it out from other questions.